# Input field border in other color for NOT NULL fields

Tags: cakephp

I would like to have the input field border in another color if the underlying field is `NOT NULL`.

After studying the CakePHP documentation I think I can somehow implement it with the [Custom Widgets](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#adding-custom-widgets) but how do I get the information if the field is `NULL` or `NOT NULL`, or does CakePHP already offer something pre-build which I didn't find?

---

**Update:**

I display all tables in the edit mode with **one** script. With this I want to avoid 50 `edit.php` scripts serving each table in the database. In this one script I generate on the fly the edit form. This means, this script is NEVER assigned to exactly one table. This is not the problem as I can parse all fields and display them properly for every special database type [date, varchar, set, int, time, ...].

Even the field description is read automatically from the table field comment which is then displayed as `title` tag when the mouse is moved over the ? symbol.

And now, as the next step, I would like to show a different border for a input field which is `NOT NULL`. This means, the different border should be shown for all fields which are displayed for the table.

I am using CakePHP 4.1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found this solution:**

Due to the fact the function has to evaluate the table schema in order to generate on the fly the form, the function *knows* which fields are `NOT NULL`. Then, when it creates the field with `$this->Form->control(..)` it adds simple in the options argument `["style" => "border: color width type"]` for these fields, which are `NOT NULL`..

If somebody has a more elegant way, please post it as an answer so I can learn something and I'll accept it.